# how can i give a boolean a value inside a function with a while loop

Tags: python, function, if-statement, while-loop, boolean

i'm trying to make a guessing game, and i want to give the user 5 chances, but the loop keeps going after the chances given if the answer is incorrect.

if the answer is correct the program will print the losing text

i think the problem is with the value of **full** but the solutions i've tried broke the code

```
def proceso(ingreso, correcto, usos, usos_completos, usos_visibles, full):
     if usos < usos_completos:
         while ingreso != correcto and not full:
             print("you have " + str(usos_visibles) + " chances")
             ingreso = input("guess the word: ")
             usos += 1
             int(usos_visibles)
             usos_visibles -= 1
         else:
             full = True

     if full:
         print("you lost. Correct answer was: " + correcto)
     else:
         print("you won")



palabra_secreta1 = "cellphone"

palabra_ingresada = ""
oportunidades = 0
limite_oportunidades = 5
contador_visible = 5
sin_oportunidades = False

print("5 oportunities")

proceso(palabra_ingresada, palabra_secreta1, oportunidades, limite_oportunidades, contador_visible, sin_oportunidades)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `break`  if the correct word is inputted and then count the number of chances taken in the while loop and then use `else` to print if the correct input has not been given after the desired number of attempts. I've removed some arguments because they seemed to be the same and I'm not sure what they mean, but maybe they're useful? Also, you should use f-strings for formatting variables into strings:

```
def proceso(correcto, usos_completos):
    usos = 0
    while usos != usos_completos:
        print(f"you have {usos_completos-usos} chances")
        ingreso = input("guess the word: ")
        if ingreso == correcto:
            print("you won")
            break
        else:
            usos += 1
    else:
        print(f"you lost. Correct answer was: {correcto}")

palabra_secreta1 = "cellphone"

limite_oportunidades = 5

print("5 oportunities")

proceso(palabra_secreta1, limite_oportunidades)
```